# "Boundaries" of cells in a cell decomposition

Tags: general-topology

In Lee's text, a cell decomposition is defined as follows:

[image]

I was wondering, based on this definition, for any $e\in \mathcal{E}$, how can one characterize $\bar{e}\setminus e$? We know that the pre-image can be written as follows (under $\Phi$):
$$\Phi^{-1}(\bar{e}\setminus e) = \Phi^{-1}(\bar{e})\setminus \Phi^{-1}(e) = D\setminus \mathrm{Int}(D) = \partial D$$
with the second equality coming from the continuity of $\Phi$. However, we cannot simply apply $\Phi$ to both sides and say that $\bar{e}\setminus e$ is contained in the union of all cells of dimensions strictly less than that of $e$. Is the above procedure correct and, if so, how can one properly characterize $\bar{e}\setminus e$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D$ is compact, the closed map lemma shows that $\Phi$ is a closed map. Because it's closed and continuous, it follows that $\Phi\big(\overline A\big) = \overline {\Phi(A)}$ for every subset $A\subseteq D$ (see Proposition 2.30 in my book). In particular,
$$
\Phi(D) = \Phi\big(\overline {\operatorname{Int}D}\big)=\overline {\Phi(\operatorname{Int} D)} = \overline e,
$$
and so
$$
\overline e\smallsetminus e = \Phi(D)\smallsetminus e = \Phi(\partial D),
$$
which is contained in the union of all cells of lower dimension.

Comment: How do yo know that $ D = \overline{\text{Int} D}$ ?

Comment: @Andarrkor:  $D$ is a cell, meaning it's homeomorphic to a closed ball. The meaning of $\text{Int} D$ in this context is the subset of $D$ corresponding to the open ball under this homeomorphism, so the statement that $D = \overline {\text{Int} D}$ is just the fact that the open ball is dense in the closed ball.

Comment: Thanks! Two more questions:

1- Does the actual interior/boundary of D concide with the interior/boundary defined this way?
2- Which is the theorem on invariance of boundary you mention in the definition? I have not been able to find it in the book.

Comment: @Andarrkor: Depends on what you mean by the "actual interior/boundary." What I'm talking about here is that D is a manifold with boundary, and I mean the interior and boundary of D in that sense. (See the paragraph before "Cell Decompositions" on page 129 of my book.) For invariance of the boundary, just look in the index.